# AngularJS routing, remove # from the URL

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I am using AngularJS routing and I used many tricks, but the '#' sign always comes in URL.

Refer below Example/Code that I Used but it is not removing # sign from the URL.

```
angular.module('mod', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', '**$locationProvider'**, 
           function($routeProvider, **$locationProvider**) {

   $routeProvider.
      when('/first', { 
           templateUrl: 'first.html',   
           controller: 'firstCtrl'
   });

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }]);
```

Does any one have solution for this? Please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've came up with the same issue and found the solution on the Docs.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

and

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

> If you configure $location to use html5Mode (history.pushState), you
>   need to specify the base URL for the application with a 
>   tag or configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by
>   passing a definition object with requireBase:false to
>   $locationProvider.html5Mode():

We've done the wrong function call. Try this and it will work. You can [check the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase) too.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this :)

Answer (score 2):

there are either of things u can do it work

you need to specify the base URL for the application with a 
 If your root of your application is different than the url (for example /my-app, then use that as your base).

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="">  
</head>
```

or you can configure

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```