# Removing the # from angularJS routing make application stop working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am tried remove the # from my angular application.

I have followed the steps in different forum.

[AngularJS routing, remove # from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628084/angularjs-routing-remove-from-the-url)

I have set the below configuration.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

The application is working as expected if I give my http://localhost/ if I try to refresh or give the complete url http://localhost/mypage/test.html it is not working routing and giving me 404. It is was working with #

http://localhost/#/mypage/test.html is working fine.

I am using chrome 51 any idea what is happening?

Comment: You also need to configure your webserver to support rewriting the URLs. See for example https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/ if you are using Apache

Comment: In that case try searching for 'angular html5mode tomcat' as I'm afraid I can't help you with tomcat configuration.